# SDS to keyless chuck adapter?

Tags: drill, adapter

I have Makita Xph07 and it is powerful enough to drill concrete, I want to use longer masonry drill bit, but all the longer bits are for SDS chuck only, is there any adapter that will allow me to use SDS bits on keyless chuck?
all the adapters I saw doing the opposite thing...

Comment: Amazon has adapters

Comment: Since we know that “yes” such a thing exists, I’m voting to close this question as a product recommendation, because asking which to buy makes it a product recommendation question.

Comment: Answers to shopping questions time out, so aren't ideal for this site. However, https://www.amazon.com/Shank-Adaptor-Power-Accessories-Hitachi/dp/B00CQAH1GS should fit. Just don't push your little drill too hard!

Comment: This is the only adapter that seems to do what I need but its not what I was looking for and it also not ship to my country :). I can't understand why its so hard to find this kind of adapter, I thought its much easier to create that than the sds to keyless

Answer (score 1):

While someone has already linked to the adapter, for occasional use why not just clamp the SDS in the chuck? If you plan to do even a medium sized project, get a proper SDS drill. Besides small holes, these little hammer drills will be frustrating. My Bosch SDS cuts through brick, block, concrete like butter - like drilling into pine, even for 3/4" holes 14" deep. And you can use the chisels to break up concrete and tile. [This](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000BB79Q6) is a well respected - and huge bang for your buck - model. I paid over $200 for mine five years ago and love it.

Comment: Using SDS in regular chuck can damage the chuck...

Answer (score 0):

i have bought standard chuck masonry bits up to 12" long. If you need anything longer I would suggest buying or renting a larger size drill matched to the job.